# Why am I receiving an error when trying to add a Button to a GridPane?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm getting an error for grid.add(button, c, r); saying "the method add(node, int, int) in the type GridPane is not applicable for the arguments (Button, int, int)". This is such a trivial thing but I cannot figure out what's wrong. I know it's saying I'm trying to put a Button where a node is supposed to be, but I've looked up examples of buttons being added to gridpanes and they have this exact syntax with no issues.

Sorry if this has been asked/answered previously, I couldn't find any question that was the same as this.

```
public class Demo extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);

        for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                int number = 10 * r + c;
                Button button = new Button();
            
                grid.add(button, c, r); 
            }
        }

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the import, might be awt ..?

Comment: Have you loaded `java.awt.Button` or `javafx.scene.control.Button`?

Comment: Strange, I had neither loaded. Typically when I create a Button, it gives the option to import it, but I didn't get that option this time and I wasn't seeing any errors with the Button itself being created. Now that I manually imported it, it's working fine. Dumb little mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, check imports to be sure that you are not importing from java.awt library?

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
```

Comment: Strange, I had neither loaded. Typically when I create a Button, it gives the option to import it, but I didn't get that option this time and I wasn't seeing any errors with the Button itself being created. Now that I manually imported it, it's working fine. Dumb little mistake. Thank you!